# Expo & Metro Bundler crash when attempting to open on Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, npm, expo, metro-bundler

On a react-native project, since a few hours, I have a huge issue : Expo doesn't want to open my App on my android emulator.

I'm doing : `expo start` in the terminal,

I have the terminal interface with the QR Code

And when I press `a` to open on android, in my terminal I can see `Opening on Android...` and nothing happens

So I've tried to use the Metro Bundler graphic interface in the web browser to open my app and when I click on the button `Run on Android device/emulator`, I can see the message `Attempting to open a simulator` and nothing happens.

I've restarted my computer many times, I've tried `npm run --clear-cache`, `expo r -c` and still, nothing happen when I want to open my App on my emulator.

4 hours of trying to solve this and I found no solutions...

EDIT : I can use my Application on my iPhone using the Tunnel connexion

EDIT : When I try to open the Application on an android emulator, expo crashes. I can't even close it with CTRL+C on the terminal

Comment: I have the exact same problem... Did you find how to resolve this ?

Comment: It was a problem caused by Android Studio. I just installed a new device and it worked

Comment: I found the solution putting graphics to software instead of Automatic my self. Thanks for answering my comment !